# Is Linq to SQL fast when using with stored procedures?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I want to use Linq to SQL for db communications. I have read many a page mentioning Linq is slow, but I like its being rapid development technique.

Please guide me using Linq to SQL with stored procedure bring any advantage in term of performance ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using stored procedures when accessing the database via LINQ-To-SQL or EF for better performance.

Using plain LINQ, which would generate SQL queries can be quite inefficient when it comes to any moderately complex query.

Comment: thanks, I am also feeling same but I dont have any logic how sp with Linq will faster then generated sql ? plz guide

Comment: @user576510 - SQL generated by L2S or EF is dependent on how the framework parses the LINQ query, and how you've written it. The generated SQL therefore may not be the most efficient, it will not utilize the TempDB or force the use of plans or indexes or specific features of the SQL language. Stored procedures allow you to do all of that and write better SQL. For very simple cases with a basic WHERE statement, LINQ would be fine given that the query would be quite straightforward.

Comment: Also you could look at it another way, in that, SQL is set-based and optimized for a given DB server, L2S or EF are frameworks that translate C# code, a language which is not set-based to SQL. So from a functionality standpoint, let set operations, filtering, unions, intersections etc reside in the DB, and all calculations, i.e. say math calculations, data analysis on given a piece of data reside in C#, you'd be using the best features of both worlds... IMHO!

Comment: Entity framework is intended to be the Ado.net data access technology moving forward. Stored procedures do not offer a performance benefit vs entity framework assuming you have knowledge of both technologies. Especially given the fact that you can execute stored procedures with entity framework. Answer Downvoted.

Comment: Also : http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html

Comment: @RobotSushi: Based on my experience, I've found that SQL stored proc do provide better performance. Especially when it comes to LINQ-To-SQL (if you've seen what LINQ-To-SQL queries look like when seen via the SQL profiler), you'll know that the generated SQL is not efficient. I would say that if your application is accessing multiple types of DB systems, then trying to keep things simple by keeping your querying code in your app would most definitely make sense. Also tuning/tweaking your stored procedures without modifying the app is big plus.

Answer (score 6):

The main advantage here is in getting the IDE to write all the plumbing for you, i.e. getting the parameters and return data sorted out.

In terms of raw performance; with a stored procedure there is no expression tree to parse, so it should be pretty quick. However, internally we have noticed occasional slowdowns in the LINQ-to-SQL *materializer*, which might impact you if you have heavy usage.

If you want the fastest performance, my advice is to look at [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), which we wrote (and released as OSS) after finding these materializer pauses. The usage is pretty simple. In particular, this neatly allows you to use dapper to do the heavy work, but still use the IDE-generated types for the data.

Internally, we don't use stored-procedures; we use a combination of:

- LINQ-to-SQL expression tree code
- LINQ-to-SQL `ExecuteQuery` (etc) code
- dapper-dot-net

The preference for *performance* is (in our experience) the last. The first is convenient to write, and is often plenty fast enough. The middle option is *fast*, but when dapper has an almost identical API (and is faster) is hard to love now ;p

Comment: Thanks @Marc, I will see dapper-dot-net this weekend. 

Regarding is your recommendation to use Linq to SQL with SP as compared to Linq to SQL with generated quires ?

Comment: @user576510 a stored proc *unless you are doing it for other reasons* adds very little here. For the simple CRUD operations I would let LINQ-to-SQL generate the TSQL itself. For more complex queries, I'd use TSQL from the C# layer via dapper (not sprocs). *Simple* queries I might leave as lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fair bit of overhead in terms of constructing the SQL.  This is particularly evident when doing bulk inserts.  Using stored procedures can help quite a bit here, as all of that generator logic is dispensed and the parameters get mapped to an SP call which is very lightweight.  For my own app, in particular with one of my tables with 100+ columns, the improvement was dramatic -- at least four or five times quicker than generating the SQL on the fly.

It's pretty easy to do, too, so long as you are the one generating your entity classes.  Just declare your extensibility methods for `Insert` and `Update` in your generated entity classes.  You'll have a handle to the entity, and from there you can make the ADO.NET connection to invoke the SP.

With all that being said, if I were you, I wouldn't go down this route until you confirm that this is where your performance bottleneck is.  For most purposes, the generated SQL performs well enough.

Comment: by "Using stored procedures can help quite a bit here, as all of that generator logic is dispensed and the parameters get mapped to an SP call which is very lightweight" do you mean sp with Linq or sp with Ado.net ?

Comment: @user, I meant SP with Linq-To-Sql.

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL is just as fast as manually writing the ado.net code to call the stored procedure.